# change CheckBoxPreferesses if normal checkbox is chacked

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

I'm working on an android application, and i have in my signup layout a checkbox for a value that can be edited from my settings (settings are sharedpreferences)
so when the user signup can check that checkbox and if this checkbox is checked so the one in my settings (CheckBoxPreferences), my question is how can i change CheckBoxPreferences value depending on if the checkbox from the signup activity is checked?

thank you

Comment: you can store value somewhere like shared preferences and based on value check or uncheck CheckBoxPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `CheckBox` value in SharedPrefernces`and based on value of`SharedPreferences`, set`CheckBoxPreference` to check/uncheck

```
boolean isCheckBoxChecked = <GetCheckBoxState>;
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PrefsName", <Mode>);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("<Key>", isCheckBoxChecked).commit();

//Retrieve SharedPreferences value and set it to CheckBoxPreference
boolean value = prefs.getBoolean("<Key>", <DefaultValue>);
CheckBoxPreference cbPref = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("<YourPreference>");
cbPref.setChecked(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer176"
            android:state_checked="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked250"
            android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer176"/>

</selector>


========================================================

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/slider_listview_row_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
        android:background="@null"
        />


You can use above xml code ..
```